# I am planning to build to survey platform from scratch using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, platform, survey, rule-engine

I am planning to build an ASP.NET survey platform, that would also provide a scripting interface. I was wondering if there is an existing framework or open source platform to give a jump start.

Also would a rule engine come in handy?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer to the question:

[Looking for the best Asp.net survey application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422690/looking-for-the-best-asp-net-survey-application/3422766#3422766)

for some interesting projects already in this space.

In a nutshell:

`The Survey Project` is one of the most mature survey applications written in ASP.NET / C#.  It's open source and has full source code available.

See here: http://www.surveyproject.info/

There are also some other survey applications and "engines" available with source code, although they don't seem to be as "mature" as the aforementioned "Survey Project".

http://surveywebpart.codeplex.com/
http://websurvey.codeplex.com/
http://surveymaster.codeplex.com/